# Multiple Package Names - Android App

Tags: android

I've got one app, and after creating a new activity it seems to have created a whole new package. That's fine because everything interacts with eachother, but will this affect uploading the app to the Google play market?

[image: Sorry, had to edit the names out but you can see what I mean by two packages.]

Comment: whole new package? Or just the end part? Can you show us an example?

Comment: this will NOT affect uploading the app to the Google play market.

Comment: I've added the image if you want to see, the two packaged names are the same apart from an extra ".etcetc" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

No it won't affect the app being uploaded to the Google Play market.

The package that matters is the one defined in your AndroidManifest.xml, for ex:

this is how it will be shown/recognized in the market